# Обертывание С++ структуры для python

Tags: c++, python, структуры

товарищи. Прошу помочь советом или указать верный путь. Предположим в С++ имеется структура такого вида:

```
struct MyStruct
{
 MyTYPE a;
 MyTYPE b;
 MyTYPE b;
}
```

Со своим дефолтным конструктором.

И существует функция(тоже в С++) которой на вход подается данная структура, а на выходе массив преобразованный в будущем в список python. Для данной функции написана обертка для python. Вопрос такой, как можно обернуть структуру так, чтобы в python файле можно было параметром передать данную структуру в уже обернутую функцию. Прошу прощения если проблема непонятна, достаточно тяжело описать ее на человеческом языке. Но если кто понимает и знает решение, заранее благодарен. Использую для обертывания boost.python.

Comment: А что такое `MyTYPE`?

Comment: @Qwertiy мой тип. В моем случае вместо MyTYPE используется BYTE

Comment: Посмотрите сюда:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040176/expose-public-struct-inside-a-class-for-boostpython

Comment: http://www.swig.org/